# php sed exec will not change $variable in a file

Tags: php, sed, exec

I'm working on a php script that uses sed to change a value in a file to whatever the $value is in the php script. Here is my code:

```
$value = red;

$color_change = exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/color-name=.*/color-name=$value/g')." /home/user/color.props");
echo "$color_change";
```

Instead of sed changing color-name in the file to red it literally changes it to $value instead. So I get color-name=$value in the file instead of color-name=red. It is as if sed isn't seeing the $value = red part in my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use " around the string instead of '

" allows variable substitution where as ' puts the value in as written.